# need a busy indicator

Tags: wpf, busyindicator

How can I display some sort of a busy indicator in my WPF application? I have a control that takes a while to load and I want the user to be informed that the data is being loaded to the control. Maybe some sort of sandglasses or a spinning circle will do?

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wpf+progress+indicator) not working today?

Comment: @BalamBalam : this is not really nice one considering you have in hand such powerful WPF framework, usability of such solution would be weird in nowadays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using pretty nice [WPF ToolKit BusyIndicator](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator)

Below is usage example:

```
<extToolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True" BusyContent="Downloading email..." >
            <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource SampleContent}"/>
</extToolkit:BusyIndicator>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`ProgressBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx) control native to WPF that you could use. If possible, I would suggest loading as much of your slow-running operations in the background on another thread (assuming it doesn't access the UI), and update the `ProgressBar` at intervals to indicate progress has been completed. Alternately, instead of updating the progress, you could set it to be continuous, in which case it will just cycle until hidden.